# UITableViewCell shadow disappears on scroll (iOS 13)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uikit, shadow

I found some regression in my app which I'm pretty sure only started now on Xcode 11.3.1 (iOS 13).

It used to work great but now we started seeing something weird.. the shadows we add to each cell suddenly disappears by themselves on tableview scroll.

[image: image description]

The app uses `UITableView` and inside delegate method `willDisplayCell:` we call this code:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    view.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0f;
    view.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
    view.layer.borderColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;

    view.layer.shadowColor = shadowColor != nil ? shadowColor.CGColor : [[UIColor lightGrayColor] CGColor];
    view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 2.0f);
    view.layer.shadowRadius = 2.0f;
    view.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0f;
    view.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
    view.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:view.bounds cornerRadius:view.layer.cornerRadius].CGPath;
});
```

I tried to play with `view.layer.zPosition` and with `view.backgroundColor=UIColor.clearColor` with no luck.

Does anyone knows what's going on there?

**Update:**

This same issue happens also in UICollectionView.

**Answering the comments:**

1. changing `UIUserInterfaceStyle` in plist to "Light" didn't help.
2. set shadowColor at the end of the method - didn't help.
3. adding shadow in cellforrow instead of willdisplaycell - didn't help

Comment: try adding  <key>UIUserInterfaceStyle</key>
 <string>Light</string> in info.plist

Comment: @BenRockey was right, if your phone has dark mode enabled than add this <key>UIUserInterfaceStyle</key> <string>Light</string> key for make your app theme light OR make Dark mode off and than check...

Comment: you are giving corner radius and clipstobounds = true to the view and then giving the shadow..it simply won't work as your border would be clipped...use two views..the outer view with shadow and inner view with corner radius...also background color of the outer view should be clear.

Comment: I've been having some issues with shadows not being applied, can you try to set the shadowColor at the end of the method?

Comment: Have you tried adding shadow in cellforrow instead of willdisplaycell ?

Comment: Personally, I would add them to inner views (or contentView) and just turn off the masking. Also, your frame should be updatedi in `layoutSubviews`.

Answer (score 0):

I was having trouble with this too. What I found to be the problem is for some reason when the cell will be displayed, the *layer.clipsToBound is reset to True*. All you need to do to fix it is when the  *tableViewDelegate* calls for *viewWillDisplayCell* set the `layer.clipsToBound = false`

That worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add shadow in awakefrom nib of the collectionview cell as bellow code.

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    view.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 2)
    view.layer.shadowRadius = 2
    view.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
    view.layer.masksToBounds = false
}
```

Comment: are you doing anything else with layer? or setting clipstobounds to view?